# MySQL Doesn't bring back data

Tags: mysql, null, rows

I have the following code:

```
SELECT q1, COUNT(q1) as Responses, 
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM `acme` WHERE q1 >= 1) AS Total, 
(COUNT(q1) / (SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM `acme` WHERE q1 >= 1 )) *100 AS Percentage
FROM `acme` WHERE q1  >= 1 GROUP BY q1 DESC
```

Very simple, there can only be four responses in the `q1` field - they are 1,2,3 or 4

See the output below:

```
q1  Responses   Total   percentage
4   109         362     30.1105
3   224         362     61.8785
2   25          362     6.9061
1   4           362     1.1050
```

Now, this works a treat if options 1,2,3 or 4 are in `q1` BUT, the problem I have is if there are no `4's` in Q1 - the code will return rows for 3,2 and 1 and not 4 (which I guess is actually correct).

So, if there were no 4's I need it to produce something like this...

```
q1  Responses   Total   percentage
4   0           253     0
3   224         253     88.53754
2   25          253     9.88142
1   4           253     1.58102
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: Do you have any master table which stores the different types of response?

Comment: You state "there can only be four responses in the q1 field - they are 1,2,3 or 4" - in which case, why do you bother with the `WHERE q1  >= 1` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
select * from (SELECT q1, COUNT(q1) as Responses, 
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM `acme` WHERE q1 >= 1) AS Total, 
(COUNT(q1) / (SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM `acme` WHERE q1 >= 1 )) *100 AS Percentage
FROM `acme` WHERE q1  >= 1 GROUP BY q1 DESC
union
select 1,0,0,0 from dual
union
select 2,0,0,0 from dual
union
select 3,0,0,0 from dual
union
select 4,0,0,0 from dual) as t group by q1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84b31/6

or you can try without the `DUAL`

```
select * from (SELECT q1, COUNT(q1) as Responses, 
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM `acme` WHERE q1 >= 1) AS Total, 
(COUNT(q1) / (SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM `acme` WHERE q1 >= 1 )) *100 AS Percentage
FROM `acme` WHERE q1  >= 1 GROUP BY q1 DESC
union
select 1,0,0,0
union
select 2,0,0,0
union
select 3,0,0,0
union
select 4,0,0,0) as t group by q1;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97031/19